# Symfony Autoload Namespace Difficulties

Tags: php, namespaces, symfony

I'm trying to autoload a class within symfony 2.  The class lives in `vendor/lessc/lessc.inc.php`  It's not loading saying the lessc class is not found.  What am I doing wrong?

From **app/autoloader.php**

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
  //...
  'Less'             => __DIR__.'/../vendor/lessc',
));
```

From **lessc.inc.php**

```
namespace Less;
class lessc { 
  //..
}
```

From **vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/LessphpFilter.php** which calls the `lessc` class.

```
namespace Assetic\Filter;
use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Less;
//...
class LessphpFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        //...
        $lc = new Less\lessc();
```

**Edit**: Solution based on advice I got:

Class path = `vendor/Less/lessc.php`

**vendor/Less/lessc.php**

```
namespace Less;
class lessc {
```

**vendor/assetic/src/Assetic/Filter/LessphpFilter.php** is the same as above.

**within a twig template**

```
 {% stylesheets
  '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/styles.less'
   filter='lessphp'
 %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
 {% endstylesheets %}
```

**app/autoloader.php**

```
'Less' => __DIR__.'/../vendor'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your class named "lessc" should be in a file named "lessc.php", you should change this line:

```
'Less'             => __DIR__.'/../vendor/lessc'
```

for this one:

```
'Less'             => __DIR__.'/../vendor'
```

You should change the name of the "lessc" dir for "Lessc".
Besides, you should move your assetic filter inside your "Less" namespace.

I hope it helped!

Comment: And if it still doesn't work, you can try use Less\lessc; instead of use Less;

Comment: Thanks for the help folks, I put the final solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Name Of Classes is `Lessc`

If You Root Folder `Less`:

```
Add Classes Name In Root Namespace Folder
```

Example:

```
use Less\Lessc;

use Less\Lessc as rootClassesOfNamespaces;
```